# Linear Algebra Projection Proof

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $B_1 = \{u_1\}$ and $B_2 = \{u_1,u_2\}$. Let $\{u_1,u_2\}$ be an orthonormal set of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $W_1 = $ Span $B_1$ and $W_2 = $ Span $B_2$, and let $y$ be in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Finally, let $\hat{y}_1 = proj_{W_1}y$, the projection of $y$ onto the subspace $W_1$, and let $\hat{y}_2 = proj_{W_2}y$. Prove that $\hat{y}_1 = proj_{W_1}\hat{y}_2$. In other words, prove that if we project $\hat{y}_2$ onto $W_1$ we get $\hat{y}_1$.

I understand all the premises, I'm just not sure why $\hat{y}_1 = proj_{W_1}\hat{y}_2$ or how to show that through a proof.

Comment: Please show us your work so far. Where are you getting stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's complete ${u_1, u_2} $ to an orthonormal basis in $\mathbb{R}^n$ which we'll call $B=sp\{u_1,u_2,u_3,...u_n\}$. Let's represent $y$ according to this base, such $y=a_1 u_1+a_2 u_2+...+a_n u_n$. Now $\hat{y_1}=Proj_{W_1}(y)=Proj_{W_1}(a_1u_1+a_2u_2+...+a_nu_n)=a_1u_1$, and $\hat{y_2}=Proj_{W_2}(y)=Proj_{W_2} (a_1u_1+a_2u_2+...+a_nu_n)=a_1u_1+a_2u_2$. Therefore, $Proj_{W_1}(\hat{y_2})=Proj_{W_1}(a_1u_1+a_2u_2)=a_1u_1=\hat{y_1}$.

Comment: Why do you need a full basis for $\mathbf R^n$ for this? Seems to me that orthogonality of $u_1$ and $u_2$ is enough.

Comment: @amd How would you just show the orthogonality of $u_1$ and $u_2$?

Comment: You assume that $u_1, u_2$ are orthogonal, which is a given since $\{u_1, u_2 \}$ is an orthogonal set. Also, you can use the projection function in the subspace $U=sp{u_1, u_2} $, and define $P=proj_{u_1} (v)$, when $P:U \rightarrow U$, if you'd like to avoid using a base in $\mathbb{R}^n$.